# debug console in visual studio code - how to test multi-line code (if statement or for loop)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Running a python program in debug mode. When the program is paused at a breakpoint, I would like to test a for loop in the debug console.

However, it appears that the debug console cannot handle multiple line statement like a typical python REPL console can.

Can one run a for loop in the debug console?

[image]

Comment: not ideal, but you can run it in a single line, like `for n in range(5): print(n)`

Comment: @arod - agreed. also, I learnt by trial and error that shift-enter does allow me to go to a new line to run quick loops in the debug console of VS Code.